# Get Character Text Change

Tags: c#, devexpress

How do I get the character before the position in RichEditControl
for example, A is before the caret, the return string should be A

and in text change I need to get the caret position

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `RichEditControl1.Document.CaretPosition` property to get the current position then just use `string.Substring(0, position.ToInt())` to get the string before the current position of the caret.

check the code snippet below:

```
private void simpleButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DevExpress.XtraRichEdit.API.Native.DocumentPosition position = richEditControl1.Document.CaretPosition;
    if (richEditControl1.Document.Text.Length > 0)
    {
        //Returns all previous text befor the caret
        XtraMessageBox.Show(richEditControl1.Document.Text.Substring(0, position.ToInt()));
        int intPosition = position.ToInt();
        if (intPosition > 0 && intPosition < richEditControl1.Document.Length)
        {
            //It will return previous character
            XtraMessageBox.Show(richEditControl1.Document.Text.Substring(intPosition - 1, 1));
        }
    }
}
```

**References:**
[How to get RepositoryItemRichEdit caret position](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q516516)
[How to get/set the caret position within the editor?](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/K18322)

Hope this help.